# Replacing delegation with cake

Tags: scala

At the moment I'm stacking features on a class with delegation

```
trait Backend {
  def product(id: Int): String
}

class MyBackend extends Backend {
  def product(id: Int) = "My product"
}

class LoggingBackend(underlying: Backend) extends Backend {
  override def product(id: Int) = {
    println(s"get product $id")
    underlying.product(id)
  }
}

class CachingBackend(underlying: Backend) extends Backend { /* ... */ }
```

Is it possible to replace this code with something like this?

```
trait Logging {
  this : Backend =>

  def product(id: Int) = {
    println(s"get product $id")
    /* Don't know what to write here */
  }
}

class MyLoggingBackend extends MyBackend with Logging
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change `Logging`:

```
trait Logging extends Backend {
  abstract override def product(id: Int) = {
    println(s"get product $id")
    super.product(id)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works just fine. Is there a way to somehow inject run-time configuration, say Redis url for `CachingBackend`?